# Regular expression, how to find all A tags which do not contain tag IMG inside it?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

Let's suppose that we have such HTML code. We need to get all `<a href=""></a>` tags which DO NOT contain `img` tag inside it.

```
<a href="http://domain1.com"><span>Here is link</span></a>
<a href="http://domain2.com" title="">Hello</a>
<a href="http://domain3.com" title=""><img src="" /></a>
<a href="http://domain4" title=""> I'm the image <img src="" /> yeah</a>
```

I'm using this regular expression to find all the a tag links:

```
preg_match_all("!<a[^>]+href=\"?'?([^ \"'>]+)\"?'?[^>]*>(.*?)</a>!is", $content, $out);
```

I can modify it like this:

```
preg_match_all("!<a[^>]+href=\"?'?([^ \"'>]+)\"?'?[^>]*>([^<>]+?)</a>!is", $content, $out);
```

But how can I tell it to exclude results containing `<img` substring inside of `<a href=""></a>`?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML :-)

Comment: I'm agree wih you, but I'm still interested in method to tell exclude some word from results using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dom is the way to go, but for the sake of interest here is the solution:

The easiest way too exclude certain matches in regular expressions is to use a 'negative look-ahead' or a 'negative look-behind'. If the negative expression is found anywhere in the string, the match fails.

Example:

```
^(?!.+<img.+)<a href=\"?\'?.+\"?\'?>.+</a>$
```

Matches:

```
<a href="http://domain1.com"><span>Here is link</span></a>
<a href="http://domain2.com" title="">Hello</a>
```

But does not match:

```
<a href="http://domain3.com" title=""><img src="" /></a>
<a href="http://domain4" title=""> I'm the image <img src="" /> yeah</a>
```

The negative look forward is this part of the string:

```
(?!.+<img.+)
```

This says don't match any strings that have any chars followed by <img, followed by any chars.

```
<a href=\"?\'?.+\"?\'?>.+</a>
```

The rest is my general match for anchor tags in html, you might want to use an alternate match expression.

You may need to omit the start and end ^ $ chars depending on your useage.

More info on look ahead / behind

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a HTML parser like the [Simple DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). You [cannot parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).