# Regular expression to find all A tags which do not contain tag IMG inside it?

Tags: php, regex

I have a HTML code:

```
<a href="/in-bai-viet--Choang-n20120711033726647.chn" target="_blank">In<img src="/Images/printer.png" alt="In bài viết này" />
</a>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://ttvn.vn/">Thiên Lam - TTVN
</a>
<a href="/tinh-yeu-hon-nhan/20120709102954599/Chay-lang-.chn" title="'abc'">
abcd
</a>
```

I need to remove all a tag  which NOT contain img tag inside it.
I'm using this regular expression:

```
preg_replace('/<a(.*)[^img](.*)<\/a>/si', '', $string);
```

I also tried `^(?!.+<img.+)<a href=\"?\'?.+\"?\'?>.+</a>$` in [Regular expression, how to find all tags A which do not contain tag IMG inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896088/regular-expression-how-to-find-all-tags-a-which-do-not-contain-tag-img-inside-i) but failed.

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't use regexp to parse HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Which language are you using? Javascript? PHP? C#? As mentioned by nhahtdh below, there are kinks in the implementation of Regex in each language. Also, there might be better ways to implement what you need in the language that you are using.

Comment: @rikitikitik: It's obviously PHP. Will add a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
(<a[^<]*>.*<img[^>]*>[^<]*</a>)
```

and replace with null string. [It tested here](http://regexr.com?31gol).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this old question doesn't have a ticked answer, so I thought I would offer a solid solution.  Ria's answer doesn't escape the / in the closing *a* tag, so it results in an error at the linked demo.  Furthermore, when the provided sample is doubled (concatenate it with itself) Ria's regex pattern fails because it is too greedy and grabs multiple *a* tags, not to mention it is more than 4x slower than my pattern.

Pattern Explanation ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/HduHPd/1)):

```
(               #Start capture group
    <a[^<]*>    #Greedily match the opening a tag, no other tags
    [^<]*       #Greedily match characters of any length before <img
    <img[^>]*>  #Greedily match the whole img tag
    [^<]*       #Greedily match characters of any length after <img
    <\/a>       #Match the closing a tag
)               #End capture group
```

The code ([demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e21636854476966eed0708f7c35dcc2b6ec39175)):

```
<?php
$string="<a href=\"/in-bai-viet--Choang-n20120711033726647.chn\" target=\"_blank\">In<img src=\"/Images/printer.png\" alt=\"In bài viết này\" />
</a>
<a target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://ttvn.vn/\">Thiên Lam - TTVN
</a>
<a href=\"/tinh-yeu-hon-nhan/20120709102954599/Chay-lang-.chn\" title=\"'abc'\">
abcd
</a>
<a href=\"/in-bai-viet--Choang-n20120711033726647.chn\" target=\"_blank\">In<img src=\"/Images/printer.png\" alt=\"In bài viết này\" />
</a>
<a target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://ttvn.vn/\">Thiên Lam - TTVN
</a>
<a href=\"/tinh-yeu-hon-nhan/20120709102954599/Chay-lang-.chn\" title=\"'abc'\">
abcd
</a>";
echo preg_replace('/(<a[^>]*>[^<]*<img[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>)\r?\n?/si',NULL,$string);
?>
```

Output:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://ttvn.vn/">Thiên Lam - TTVN
</a>
<a href="/tinh-yeu-hon-nhan/20120709102954599/Chay-lang-.chn" title="'abc'">
abcd
</a>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://ttvn.vn/">Thiên Lam - TTVN
</a>
<a href="/tinh-yeu-hon-nhan/20120709102954599/Chay-lang-.chn" title="'abc'">
abcd
</a>
```

While this question has likely been resolved in real life and/or no longer matters, I just wanted to tie up this loose end.